# Why would you upload assets directly to S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, cloud-hosting

I have seen quite a few code samples/plugins that promote uploading assets directly to S3.  For example, if you have a user object with an avatar, the file upload field would load directly to S3.

The only way I see this being possible is if the user object is already created in the database and your S3 bucket + path is something like

```
user_avatars.domain.com/some/id/partition/medium.jpg
```

But then if you had an image tag that tried to access that URL when an avatar was not uploaded, it would yield a bad result.  How would you handle checking for existence?

Also, it seems like this would not work well for most has many associations.  For example, if a user had many songs/mp3s, where would you store those and how would you access them.

Also, your validations will be shot.

I am having trouble thinking of situations where direct upload to S3 (or any cloud) is a good idea and was hoping people could clarify either proper use cases, or tell me why my logic is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why pay for storage/bandwidth/backups/etc. when you can have somebody in the cloud handle it for you?

S3 (and other Cloud-based storage options) handle all the headaches for you. You get all the storage you need, a good distribution network (almost definitely better than you'd have on your own unless you're paying for a premium CDN), and backups.

Allowing users to upload directly to S3 takes even more of the bandwidth load off of you. I can see the tracking concerns, but S3 makes it pretty easy to handle that situation. If you look at the direct upload methods, you'll see that you can force a redirect on a successful upload.

Amazon will then pass the following to the redirect handler: `bucket`, `key`, `etag`

That should give you what you need to track the uploaded asset after success. Direct uploads give you the best of both worlds. You get your tracking information and it unloads your bandwidth.

Check this link for details: [Amazon S3: Browser-Based Uploads using POST](http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though.  I totally understand why I would want to store stuff on S3.  I do it right now.  What I don't understand is how you would upload directly to S3 without using your server as a conduit for validation, and tracking the asset you uploaded in a database.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  I guess the only thing you lose here is any post-processing of images unless you download, post-process, and then upload the altered images.

Comment: @Tony - Glad to help. As for post-processing, that might be a use-case where you want to proxy the upload. Having the user directly upload to S3, you then having to download and re-upload seems a bit of a waste.

Comment: I agree, thanks again for the link.  I should have looked at the docs more carefully but surprisingly none of the 50 file upload articles I have read mention anything about it.

Comment: though for the advertised examples of 'avatar', there is no way to verify that the uploaded file is indeed an image

Answer (score 3):

If you are hosting your Rails application on Heroku, the reason could very well be that Heroku doesn't allow file-uploads larger than 4MB:
http://docs.heroku.com/s3#direct-upload

So if you would like your users to be able to upload large files, this is the **only** way forward.

Comment: Yea I recently heard about this....so then how would you process an image larger than 4MB with an app on Heroku.  Seems like a pretty big limitation and I'm guessing there's a solution

Comment: You first upload direct to S3. Then, via AJAX, you tell your app about the newly uploaded file. Your app can then access the file on S3 to do post processing (e.g. thumbnailing) and register it in the database (e.g. in Paperclip or Attachment_fu). Code examples: http://gist.github.com/575842 or http://tnux.net/2010/01/17/swfupload-direct-to-amazon-s3-in-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Some more code examples: Sample project using Rails 3, Flash and MooTools-based FancyUploader to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-FancyUploader ... and my other sample project using Rails 3, Flash/Silverlight/GoogleGears/BrowserPlus and jQuery-based Plupload to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-Plupload

Answer (score 0):

Remember how web servers work.

Unless you're using a sort of async web setup like you could achieve with Node.JS or Erlang (just 2 examples), then *every* upload request your web application serves ties up an entire process or thread while the file is *being uploaded*.

Imagine that you're uploading a file that's several megabytes large.  Most internet users don't have tremendously fast uplinks, so your web server spends a lot of time doing nothing.  While it's doing all of that nothing, it can't service any other requests.  Which means your users start to get long delays and/or error responses from the server.  Which means they start using some other website to get the same thing done.  You can always have more processes and threads running, but each of those costs additional memory which eventually means additional $.

By uploading straight to S3, in addition to the bandwidth savings that Justin Niessner mentioned and the Heroku workaround that Thomas Watson mentioned, you let Amazon worry about that problem. You can have a single-process webserver effectively handle very large uploads, since it punts that actual functionality over to Amazon.

So yeah, it's more complicated to set up, and you have to handle the callbacks to track things, but if you deal with anything other than really small files (and even in those cases), why cost yourself more money?

Edit: fixing typos